# How to pass parameters to a Powershell script file custom action

Tags: powershell, installation, custom-action, advanced-installer

I have a Powershell Deferred Custom Action that I want to change from [In-line Script](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-actions-list.html#powershell-script) to [Script From File](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-actions-list.html#powershell-script-from-file). The problem is that the Advanced Installer GUI no longer has a "Parameters" field to let me pass MSI installer public properties into the script:

Parameters field for Inline:

[image]

No Parameters field for File:

[image]

How can I pass values into a Powershell Script File, similar to how I could for an in-line script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a property simply include a line with the following syntax in your script:

```
$propValue = AI_GetMsiProperty YOUR_PROP
```

Where YOUR_PROP is the property name.

To set a property simply include a line with the following syntax in your script:

```
AI_SetMsiProperty YOUR_PROP <VALUE>
```

Where YOUR_PROP is the property and  is the value assigned to it.

For details, please check the [PowerShell CA article](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-actions-list.html#powershell-script).